# Postman 200 status null message Insightly CRM

Tags: api, postman, crm, insightly

I am currently doing some Postman API requests to Insightly CRM.

I got success with most calls. However, I am doing a `GET` request on 'Tags' but getting no JSON formatting response back. Instead I am receiving a 200 status message with '**null**'

Anyone explain what null message could be?

Comment: each message only has a "Null", nothing else?

Comment: Yes only null for 'Tags'. If my params are incorrect I will get 404 & JSON error message. On other requests for e.g Contacts it fires back 200 w/ proper records/data in JSON format.